# Calculating datetime between two rows, showing one with more than 60 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have for example a table

```
id, datetime

1 2014-01-01 01:23:23
2 2014-01-01 01:25:23
3 2014-01-01 01:26:23
4 2014-01-01 01:26:25
7 2014-01-01 01:27:25
8 2014-01-01 01:27:26
```

I want receive a list of id's that between them there is more than 60 second difference.

My table is very large, when i try to run my query it takes very long. Is there an easier way? Id's in the table are not autoincrement, they can jump in number between them.

```
SELECT A.id, A.datetime, (B.datetime - A.datetime) AS timedifference
FROM MyTable A CROSS JOIN MyTable B
WHERE B.id IN (SELECT MIN(C.id) FROM MyTable C WHERE C.id > A.id 
AND C.datetime between '2014-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-10 00:01:00') 
AND A.datetime between '2014-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-10 00:01:00'  
AND B.datetime between '2014-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-10 00:01:00'  
having timedifference > 60 
ORDER BY A.id ASC;
```

Comment: Do you mean 'more than 60 seconds between consecutive ids?'

Comment: yes, the idea is if longer than 60 seconds between rows

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to find where there is a gap of one minute or more.  I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select a.id, a.datetime,
       (select id
        from mytable b
        where b.datetime > a.datetime + interval 1 minute
        order by b.datetime
        limit 1
       ) as nextid
from mytable a
where A.datetime between '2014-08-10 00:00:00' AND '2014-08-10 00:01:00'
having nextid is not null;
```

For performance, you want an index on `mytable(datetime, id)`.

Comment: i tried running it, it didnt bring results like my first query above. I waited for longer than 10 minutes. So my query in the question was faster.

Comment: @Roninio . . . Did you have the index properly defined for the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,datetime DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2014-01-01 01:23:23'),
(2,'2014-01-01 01:25:23'),
(3,'2014-01-01 01:26:23'),
(4,'2014-01-01 01:26:25'),
(7,'2014-01-01 01:27:25'),
(8,'2014-01-01 01:27:26');

SELECT a.id
     , TIMEDIFF(b.datetime,a.datetime)
  FROM (SELECT x.*, @i:=@i+1 rank FROM my_table x, (SELECT @i:=0) i ORDER  BY x.id) a
  JOIN (SELECT x.*, @j:=@j+1 rank FROM my_table x, (SELECT @j:=0) j ORDER  BY x.id) b
    ON b.rank = a.rank + 1
   AND b.datetime > a.datetime + INTERVAL 60 SECOND;

+----+---------------------------------+
| id | TIMEDIFF(b.datetime,a.datetime) |
+----+---------------------------------+
|  1 | 00:02:00                        |
+----+---------------------------------+
```